# how to define bigquery schema when build apache beam data pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I create a data pipeline with apache beam, but it can not insert the data to bigquery.

I use beam.ParDo to process the data, and yield the data row by row,

below is the code.

```
project = 'project_name'
dataset = 'XXX'

class parser_data(beam.DoFn):
    
    def process(self, data):
        ZZ = [{"NN":d["NNN"], "descrip":d} for d in data["colZ"]]
        ret = pd.DataFrame(data['colD'])
        ret["colA"] = data["colA"]
        ret["colB"] = data["colB"]
        ret["colC"] = data["colC"]
        
        ret = pd.merge(ret, pd.DataFrame(ZZ), on=["NN"], how="left")
        ret = ret[["colA", "colB", "colC", "NN", "sample", "descrip"]]
        print(ret)
        ret_dict = ret.to_dict("records")
        print(ret_dict)
        for i in range(len(ret_dict)):
            yield ret_dict[i]
        
        
options = PipelineOptions(
    runner = 'DirectRunner',
    region = 'us-west1',
    project = project,
    job_name = "test-tmp",
    streaming = False,
    setup_file = './setup.py',
    subnetwork = "XXXXXXX",
    service_account_email = "XXXXXX",
    temp_location='XXXXXX',
    staging_location="XXXXXX",
    use_public_ips = False
)

d = {
    'colA': '1', 
    'colB': 'Strawberry', 
    'colC': 2,
    'colD': [{"NN":"AA", "sample":1}, {"NN":"AA", "sample":2}, {"NN":"BB", "sample":3}, {"NN":"CC", "sample":4}, {"NN":"CC", "sample":5}], 
    'colZ': [{"NNN":"AA", "name":"123", "timeperiod":"152"}, {"NNN":"BB", "name":"1212513", "timeperiod":"1952"}, {"NNN":"CC", "name":"13", "timeperiod":"14152"}], 
}

schema = {
    'fields':[
        {'name': 'colA', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'colB', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'colC', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'NN', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'sample', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {
            'name': 'descrip', 'type': 'RECORD', 'mode': 'NULLABLE', 
            'fields':[
                {"name": "NNN", "type": "STRING", 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
                {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
                {"name": "timeperiod", "type": "STRING", 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            ]
        },
    ]
}

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    data = (
        pipeline | 'get data' >> beam.Create([d])
    )
     
    ret_A = (
        data | "Process A data " >> beam.ParDo(parser_data())
             | "Insert data into BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                 f"{project}:{dataset}.TestJsonData",
                 schema=schema,
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
             )
    )
```

The error is below

RuntimeError: BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_testtmp_LOAD_STEP_820_9672b886a985a9a36a9c3805cee3be5e_3f26019c07d746ef92c0893574156f5b failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto
location: 'gs://XXXXXXXX/dataflow_temp/bq_load/db11e8430c10470382be2565136d53fb/{project}.{dataset}.TestJsonData/39e0d645-8484-4033-a1c4-3e4a825d6fee'
message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.'
reason: 'invalid'> [while running '[25]: Insert data into BQ/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs']

Also the print function show the data, so I think the problem is in the bigquery schema, but I can not find it

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you write the full error please ?

Comment: update the error. @ValentinRicher

Comment: It seems that Beam cannot find data at specific location `BQ/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs`

Comment: Any idea to fix this problem?